# How to remove content within a parent div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Within the parent div, I am trying to add/appedn the html content show in the javascript below.  I am also trying to remove the existing html, the pre-existing html in the parent div which is the everything that has class like.

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.like').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().append("<a href = '#' class = 'unlike'><div class = 'heart'></div></a>");
            // $(this).parent().('.like').empty();

            console.log('liked');
        })
    })
 </script>



                   <div>                  
                    <a href = "#" class = 'like'>
                        <div class = 'coal'></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Removing previous html

```
$('.like').click(function () {
  $(this).parent()
  .html('');
  return false;
})
```

This will remove the HTML codes and the next step will add the html that you want to be added.

#### Append the code

```
$('.like').click(function () {
  $(this).parent()
  .append('<a href = '#' class = 'unlike'><div class = 'heart'></div></a>');
  return false;
})
```

So instead of that try to just replacing the previous code with the newer one.

#### Replacing the previous html with newer one

This would do the trick

```
$('.like').click(function () {
  $(this).parent()
  .html('<a href = '#' class = 'unlike'><div class = 'heart'></div></a>');
  return false;
})
```

What does this code do?

This will first get executed when you click on the element with class `like`. Then it will go for the parent element, and update its html code; which means everything inside it, to the code that you'll provide inside the brackets. Then the `return false` is a replacement for `e.preventDefault` you can use that one if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).parent().html("<a href = '#' class = 'unlike'><div class = 'heart'></div></a>");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().('.like').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.like').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).parent().append("<a href = '#'   class ='unlike'><div class = 'heart'>unlike</div></a>");

            $(this).parent().find('.like').remove();

           console.log('liked');
        })
    })
```

Check the working [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/pY6xf/)

Hoe this helps..